# Regex: Match char + new line before (new line new line)

Tags: python, python-re

String:

```
testing = "\nHello\nMy name is blah blah blah\nNice to meet you\nPS: Wait a second, I thought I know you.\nRegards\n\nUnknown\n\nHang on a minute\nI'm not done talking\n\nRegards\nOh OK"
```

which prints:

```
Hello
My name is blah blah blah
Nice to meet you
PS: Wait a second, I thought I know you.
Regards

Unknown

Hang on a minute
I'm not done talking

Regards
Oh OK
```

Desired outcome:

```
My name is blah blah blah
Nice to meet you
PS: Wait a second, I thought I know you.
Regards
```

Attempted solution:

```
test = re.search('(Hello)([\s\S]*)(\n\n)', testing).group(2)
```

which returns:

```
\nMy name is blah blah blah\nNice to meet you\nPS: Wait a second, I thought I know you.\nRegards\n\nUnknown\n\nHang on a minute\nI'm not done talking
```

However, this misses the first '\n\n' in between which I think has to do with the [\s\S]. Any way we could end the search on the first '\n\n'?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make testing.split("\n\n") and take the first element of the resulting list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` repetitor is *greedy*, it matches as much as possible until the `\n\n` (which is the last occurrence in the string). Put a question mark behind it to make it *non-greedy* so it matches as little as possible: until the first occurrence where it matches `\n\n`:

```
test = re.search('(Hello)([\s\S]*?)(\n\n)', testing).group(2)
print(test)
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
My name is blah blah blah
Nice to meet you
PS: Wait a second, I thought I know you.
Regards
```